# Typescript - the type of property that depends on another optional property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, conditional-statements, union

I have a component in React

```
const Faq = ({ shortVersion, data }: FaqProps) => { }
```

With defined types

```
type FaqProps =
  | {
      shortVersion: true;
      data: ShortFaqData[];
    }
  | {
      shortVersion: false;
      data: ExtendedFaqData[];
    };
```

And it works

```
const testDataShort: ShortFaqData[]
const testDataExtended: ExtendedFaqData[]
<Faq shortVersion={false} data={testDataExtended} />
<Faq shortVersion data={testDataShort} />
```

But I would like shortVersion not to have to be false, but could also be optional

so I tried this

```
type FaqProps =
  | {
      shortVersion: true;
      data: ShortFaqData[];
    }
  | {
      shortVersion?: false;
      data: ExtendedFaqData[];
    };
```

And this

```
type FaqProps =
  | {
      shortVersion: true;
      data: ShortFaqData[];
    }
  | {
      shortVersion: false | undefined;
      data: ExtendedFaqData[];
    };
```

And it not work for case without shortVersion (it works when i pass shortVersion)

[image: case with passed shortVersion]

[image: case without passed shortVersion]

Is it possible to make the IDE suggest the correct type for data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, with overloads. Here's my simplified version of your real-world problem:

```
type Props = {
    flag: true;
    data: number;
} | {
    flag?: false;
    data: string;
};
```

Normally, you would have something like this:

```
function Comp(props: Props) {
```

With overloads to describe the props (instead of relying on discriminated unions):

```
function Comp(props: { flag?: false; data: string }): JSX.Element;
function Comp(props: { flag: true; data: number }): JSX.Element;
function Comp(props: Props) {
```

And now you'll get the correctly suggested type:

```
<Comp data={} />; // hover over 'data' - it's shown as `string`!
```

However, I don't think you should rely on this workaround. Instead you should just bring this problem up to the maintainers as an issue and get it fixed. This behavior is obviously not ideal and should be corrected. I can't really think of a reason why this would be the desired behavior.

Hopefully you can apply this example to your real-world problem.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4BYAKCpgE8wk4AFHMAZzgF44BvKuAXEwAbFAHMAXHBhQArkgqVBcACYoYKKQDtZIAEZIoigL5wAPr36CR4gPxTMKYWwVWBajVLYzgWsScUqFSQ0USIhWS0MYAgtOABhXDAACjBWNikeIVExeyEnF1JVdU04byhfMThjAEopACkAZQANADoAUWEkECQtGEVg0JRwzEjo2ISk1PTM7PEpGXkij1KdfUNqurgmts7u3v6gkLDGUaiYGLjE8GmIdikWO7YtnY6unr7AygAea7A5qorTg8AAMpgA9AA+RS-JIA4GOZxIUxAnj4fAQ6FUWHgYoaYGYorg8FwAAWEAAbhtKRsAOQrWlwAC0cGAMFpHDY5IA7nEUBwAAblSoCgCEQA)

Comment: Yes, this is it! I was able to apply this to my case. Thank you.